# Retrieve data from Sql Table according to described scenario

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table with following columns

```
Id, Name, Date (FORMAT: Y-m-d H:i:s)
```

Now I want to retrieve data of following form

```
Count Year
3 2013
5 2014
```

It is showing total no of records generated in different years

For example If I have following data:

```
1 Manish 2013-10-01 23:12:12
2 Tarun 2013-10-02 23:12:12
3 Pankaj 2014-10-02 23:12:12
4 Pankaj 2015-10-02 23:12:12,
```

Then it will return me following data:

```
Count Year
2 2013
1 2014
1 2015
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. But what did _you_ tried?

Comment: Yes, But I am not getting any clue to retrieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(*) as cnt,
       year(date) year_of_date
from your_table
group by year_of_date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select year(date) as Year,count(*) as Total
from my_table
group by year(date)
```